# problem in displaying foreignkey objects in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having two models Patient and Ipd, Patient can have multiple Ipd. I am trying to get Patient Info in IpdForm but don't know where I am getting wrong

I have already tried "qs = Ipd.objects.get(patient__id=patient_id)" , "qs = Ipd.objects.filter(patient__id=patient_id)" but nothing worked

models.py :

```py
class Patient(models.Model): 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20);
    address = models.TextField();
    patient_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True);
    gender= models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=10)
    consultant = models.CharField(choices=CONSULTANT, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class Ipd(models.Model):

    reason_admission = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    presenting_complaints = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    ipd_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    date_of_admission = models.DateField(("Date"),
        default=datetime.date.today)  
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, default = "")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name
```

forms.py :

```py
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['name','phone','address','patient_id','consultant','Gender']

class IpdForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ipd

        fields = ['patient', 'reason_admission', 'presenting_complaints', 
                  'rooms', 'date_of_admission']
```

views.py:

```py
@login_required
def show(request, patient_id):
    patient = Patient.objects.filter(pk=patient_id)
    return render(request, 'show.html', {'patient': patient})

@login_required
def new(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = PatientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.save():
                return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Patient is successfully created.', 'alert-success'))
            else:
                return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
        else:
            return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        form = PatientForm()
        return render(request, 'new.html', {'form':form})

@login_required
def edit(request, patient_id):

    if request.POST:
        patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=patient_id)
        form = PatientForm(request.POST, instance=patient)

        if form.is_valid():

            if form.save():
                return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Patient is successfully updated.', 'alert-success'))
            else:
                return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
        else:
            return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        form = PatientForm(instance=patient)
        return render(request, 'edit.html', {'form':form})



@login_required
def ipd(request, patient_id):
    object = get_object_or_404(Ipd, patient__patient_id=patient_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)
        if formtwo.is_valid():
            instance = formtwo.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse(formtwo.errors) 
    else:
        formtwo = IpdForm()

    return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'object': object, 'form2': formtwo})
```

urls.py :

```
url(r'^order/ipd/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.ipd, name='ipd'),
```

html :

```
<div class="card-panel">                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Name : {{ab.name}}</span> <br>                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Phone : {{ a.phone  }}</span><br>                                                  
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Address : {{ a.address  }}</span><br>                                              
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Gender : {{ a.Gender  }}</span><br>                                            
</div>
```

Comment: Does Ipd.objects.get(patient_id=patient_id) throws you an exception?

Comment: Sorry @hagyn, getting error "Ipd matching query does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in this code you posted.

1. You shouldn't add a default value to a ForeignKey field, especially not a string.
2. Inside your `views.py` when you do `form.save` you're not calling the `save()` method, which is a function, therefore, nothing will be saved in your form/model.
3. Your queryset doesn't access the field you want and it should throw an error.
4. Please, do not call variables/querysets like `a`, `b`...

Having said that, your `views.py` should look something like this:

**EDITED**:
Just realised the main issue here is that you're retuning the queryset *ONLY* on the `GET` method and not on the `POST`. I don't know if that's by design or not. I'm editing my answer considering that that's *NOT* by design. Also, since we're changing the `models.py` make sure to run the migrations again.

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


@login_required
def ipd(request, patient_id):
    object = get_object_or_404(Ipd, patient__patient_id=patient_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)
        if formtwo.is_valid():
            instance = formtwo.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse(formtwo.errors) 
    else:
        formtwo = IpdForm()

    return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'object': object, 'form2': formtwo})
```

**html**

```html
<div class="card-panel">                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Name : {{object.patient.name}}</span> <br>                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Phone : {{ object.patient.phone  }}</span><br>                                                  
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Address : {{ object.patient.address  }}</span><br>                                              
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Gender : {{ object.patient.gender  }}</span><br>                                            
</div>
```

**models.py**

```py
class Ipd(models.Model):

    reason_admission = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    presenting_complaints = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    ipd_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    date_of_admission = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)  
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name
```

Comment: I've edited the answer. No need for loop. Please, check the answer now.

Comment: Thank You @HigorRossato!, but there still error "No Ipd matches the given query". and one more question do I need to add ForeignKey field(patient) in the template as it creates dropdown in the  form and I want to link the Ipd with patient directly with id

Comment: Can you print on your views.py what's coming inside the `patient_id` variable, please? With the code I've provided you should get a 404 instead of this error you're saying. I'm gonna edited my answer again, please update your code as well.

Comment: Hello @HigorRossato Sir! I have update my views.py , The patient_id is having primarykey that is related to patient

Comment: Is it a string, integer?! Like I said, if the id that’s being passed to your view is not found, Django will throw a 404 error. If that’s not happening, your code doesn’t look like my answer. If there’s no 404 that means your query has something inside it.

Comment: it is an integer

Comment: let me tell you in detail , i am trying to create a hospital management app in which patient get there unique id for regular checkup , and if they want to get admitted in hospital then there information will get directly linked with ipd form ,  when i go on ipd form the information related to the patient is not displaying and now the 404 error occurs

Comment: Hello Sir! I think I was unable to explain the right problem of mine, I am having two form one creates patient object and another form is related to patient which contains patient info. I have not created any Ipd Object yet, that query will not work for that, I want to add patient object in my new Ipd Form ,Can You Help me with that I have been searching for an answer from a long time, Please Help Me